# How find this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^2$

Tags: limits

> Find the
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^2$$

maybe can use 
$$\sqrt[n]{n}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln{n}}=1+\dfrac{1}{n}\ln{n}+o(\dfrac{\ln{n}}{n})$$
so
$$(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^2\approx \dfrac{\ln^2{n}}{n^2}$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln^2{n}}{n}=0?$$

My methods is true? and have other methods? Thank you

Comment: To me, this is perfectly correct and well done. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\ln \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^2\right) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln n + 2 
\ln\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)\right)
\\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln n + 2 \ln \left(e^\frac{\ln n}{n} - 1\right)\right)
\\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln n  + 2 \ln\left(1 + \dfrac{\ln n}{n} + O\left(\dfrac{\ln^2 n}{2n^2}\right)-1\right)\right)
\\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln n + 2 \ln\left(\dfrac{\ln n}{n}\right)\right)
\\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\ln n + 2 \ln \ln n - 2 \ln n\right)
\end{align}$$

The logarithm diverges towards negative infinity (since $\ln n \gg \ln \ln n$).  So the limit approaches zero.